# Create node with namespace

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to build some XML.  I need to create a node in a namespace that declares that same namespace.  As usual with XML, this process is proving to be annoyingly difficult.  I need XML that looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bar:foo xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.com">
  <bar:baz>baz</bar:baz>
</bar:foo>
```

This (obviously) doesn't give it to me:

```
builder=Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  # Doesn't put foo in the bar namespace
  xml.foo( "xmlns:bar" => "http://www.bar.com") do
    xml['bar'].baz "baz"
  end
end
```

Neither does this:

```
builder=Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  # undefined method `namespace_definitions' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x3fcc11b590ec name="document">
  xml['bar'].foo( "xmlns:bar" => "http://www.bar.com") do
    xml['bar'].baz "baz"
  end
end
```

How do I get Nokogiri to give me the XML I want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding namespace using Nokogiri's XML Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009842/adding-namespace-using-nokogiris-xml-builder)

Comment: Yep, it's a duplicate, I didn't see that before I posted, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh, here we go: [Adding namespace using Nokogiri's XML Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009842/adding-namespace-using-nokogiris-xml-builder)

Apparently you either can't do this during creation, or it's so difficult that even SO can't figure it out.  But you *can* do it after creation:

```
builder=Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.foo( "xmlns:bar" => "http://www.bar.com") do
    xml['bar'].baz "baz"
  end
end
root=builder.doc.root
ns=root.namespace_definitions.first # because thankfully there's only one namespace here
root.namespace=tns
```

That was annoying, though.