# Why does Nokogiri give me a namespace type error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, savon

I am consuming a webservice which is SOAP-based. I am using Savonrb to invoke the service via a POST request. I am building the XML using Nokogiri and send it to the service using Savonrb.

My application is built using Rails 3.1. The service is working on my localhost, but when we tested it in production there is intermittent error and I get the following error:

```
TypeError (Nokogiri::XML::Namespace can't be coerced into Nokogiri::XML::Namespace)
```

Can anyone let me know what that error message means?

This is my code to build it:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new
builder.Envelope{
 builder.parent.namespace = builder.parent.add_namespace_definition("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
 builder['soapenv'].Body{
  builder['ns0'].GetParty("xmlns:ns0" => "http://www.cisco.com/cixs2.0/oagis", "xmlns:ns1" => "http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9"){
    builder['ns1'].ApplicationArea{
      builder['ns1'].Sender{
        builder['ns1'].LogicalID_  sender_information['LogicalID']
        builder['ns1'].ComponentID_  sender_information['ComponentID']
        builder['ns1'].TaskID_   sender_information['TaskID']
        builder['ns1'].ReferenceID_  sender_information['ReferenceID']
        builder['ns1'].AuthorizationID_    sender_information['AuthorizationID']
      }
      builder['ns1'].CreationDateTime_   DateTime.now.to_s('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz')
      builder['ns1'].BODID(1214201110)
    }
    builder['ns0'].DataArea{
      builder['ns0'].Get(get_condition){
        builder['ns1'].Expression('expressionLanguage' => "String" ){
          builder.text "All"
        }
        builder.__send__ :insert, Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(hierarchy)

        builder.__send__ :insert, Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(search_condition)

        builder['ns0'].SearchCriteria{
          builder['ns0'].MatchAlgorithm("EXACT_SEARCH")
          builder.__send__ :insert, Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(search_type)
          builder['ns0'].SearchSource(search_source){
            builder.text "DEFAULT"
          }
          builder['ns0'].ParallelSearchIndicator('true')

          builder['ns0'].StopWhenResultFoundIndicator('true')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
return builder.to_xml
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone let me know what that error message means?

Yes--fubar.  The first thing I would try is the example in the docs (scroll down to the Namespaces section):

http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html

If that doesn't work, check out the ideas here:

[Adding namespace using Nokogiri's XML Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009842/adding-namespace-using-nokogiris-xml-builder)

Comment: It is working fine when I run it in development mode. I get this error only when i run it in production mode. There has to be something more to it. could it be thread issue. Is nokogiri thread safe? how do i test this in development mode