# Nokogiri - how to create a node tag like "<dc:publisher>"

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, nodes

I need to create some tags with "dc:" in the name: "<dc:publisher>". I tried many ways without success, I just can create regular tags like "<publisher>". Here is the code:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => "UTF-8") do |xml|
    xml.channel {
      xml.title  { xml.cdata "The Title" }
      xml.date Time.now.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
      xml.link "http://..."
      xml.description { xml.cdata "Lorem...." }
      xml.language "pt-br"
      xml.publisher { xml.cdata "John Doe" }
    }
end
```

Comment: That's a namespace. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009842/adding-namespace-using-nokogiris-xml-builder

Comment: Thanks @lmz your tip solve the problem.

I use  `xml.doc.root.add_namespace_definition("dc", "http://foo.net")` and now I can use `xml["dc"].publisher "John Doe"`. I just don't know why I have to inform a url in the namespace definition...

Comment: I am pretty sure that `"http://foo.net"` is not the right string to use there. I hope that's just an example. If not: http://web.resource.org/rss/1.0/modules/dc/

Comment: Yep, in fact I did not use the "foo.net" string :), I put this here just to fill the space. But I'm reading some article to clarify my mind. Thanks and regards.