# How to use a colon (":") in a Nokogiri node name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I would like the node name in the following code to be "`node:name`" but instead the name is put into the text of the field.

```
require 'nokogiri'

file = File.new("/Users/user_a/code/xmler/test.xml", "w+")

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do  |xml|
  xml.node:name do
    
  end
end

file << builder.to_xml
file.close
puts builder.to_xml
```

How can I use the colon or other special characters in a node name with Nokogiri?

Comment: You forgot to close the file.

Comment: What is the preferred method to do that?

Comment: You can do it with simply `file.close`, but the preferred method is to open it with a block, it will then managing its own closing, even if exceptions are raised. `File.open("...", "w+") { |file| file << builder.to_xml }`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I see it, you have three options:

1. You're using namespaces

   Then you can declare the namespace and use the `xml[]` method:

   ```ruby
   builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
     xml.root('xmlns:node' => 'http://example.com') do
       xml['node'].name
     end
   end
   ```

   Output:

   ```xml
   <root xmlns:node="http://example.com">
     <node:name/>
   </root>
   ```

   This method is a bit trickier if you want to add a namespace onto the root element though. See "[How to create an XML document with a namespaced root element with Nokogiri Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1829425/214790)".
2. You're *not* using namespaces but want/need an element name with a colon:

   In this case, you need to send the method named "node:name" to the `xml` block parameter. You can do this with the normal ruby `send` method:

   ```ruby
   builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
     xml.root do
       xml.send 'node:name'
     end
   end
   ```

   this outputs:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
     <node:name/>
   </root>
   ```
3. You're not sure what this “namespace” business is all about:

   In this case you're probably best avoiding using colons in your element names.

   An alternative could be to use `-` instead. If you did this you'd need to use method 2. above, but with `xml.send 'node-name'`. I include this option because you don't mention namespaces in your question, and colons are used in them (as method 1. shows) so you're safer not using colons to avoid any future problems.

Comment: I'm building a web-service around a pre-existing xml standard, so I don't have an option and must to use the predefined schema. You are correct in number 3, i'm starting to see how the namespace relates to the xsd documents I have but don't completely understand namespaces yet. My xml standard seems to be made with nodes from various different namespaces, 4 of them, 2 xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xs seem to reference w3.org so I think they are general and not specific to my standard.

Answer (score 1):

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do  |xml|
  xml.send("foo:bar") do
  end
end


?> puts builder.to_xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo:bar/>
```