# How to create xml element with attribute with colon in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, nokogiri

i am new to Ruby on Rails , I m trying to generating a xml file using Nokogiri.  It is working fine as we expected but one scenario unable to generate attributes, below is the example

**Expecting**

```
<tag:tagGuideline>
    <tagClassCd>54341</tagClassCd>
    <tagClassCdDesc>test description</tagClassCdDesc>
</tag:tagGuideline>
```

i did something , but it is creating differently

```
 <tag:tagGuideline>
    <tag:tagClassCd>54341</tag:tagClassCd>
    <tag:tagClassCdDesc>test description</tag:tagClassCdDesc>
   </tag:tagGuideline>
```

Here is my working code

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
      xml.root('xmlns:tag' => 'v1') {
       xml['tag'].tagGuideline do 
        xml.ClassCd '54341'
        xml.ClassCdDesc 'test description'
       end           
      }
    end
    puts builder.to_xml
```

Comment: That's an xml namespace, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829425/how-to-create-an-xml-document-with-a-namespaced-root-element-with-nokogiri-build

Comment: #dbugger :  thanks for you reply, how can i remove xml name space in child attributes , i checked your ref example even that one also giving same output.   <foo:root xmlns:foo="url">
  <foo:child>
    <foo:test>hello</foo:test>
  </foo:child>
</foo:root>